# php conversions filter issue. mcrypt is installed, but not on the list of filters

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying to implement the "Encryption Filters" from example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/filters.encryption.php:

```
$iv = substr(md5('iv'.$passphrase, true), 0, 8);
$key = substr(md5('pass1'.$passphrase, true) . 
               md5('pass2'.$passphrase, true), 0, 24); 
$opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key);

$fp = fopen('secret-file.enc', 'wb');
stream_filter_append($fp, 'mcrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
fwrite($fp, 'Secret secret secret data');
fclose($fp);
```

It gives me following warning:

> Warning: stream_filter_prepend() [function.stream-filter-prepend]: unable to locate filter "mcrypt.tripledes"

I have mcrypt installed and functioning.

Here is the print of mcrypt_list_algorithms():

```
Array ( [0] => cast-128 [1] => gost [2] => rijndael-128 [3] => twofish [4] => arcfour [5] => cast-256 [6] => loki97 [7] => rijndael-192 [8] => saferplus [9] => wake [10] => blowfish-compat [11] => des [12] => rijndael-256 [13] => serpent [14] => xtea [15] => blowfish [16] => enigma [17] => rc2 [18] => tripledes )
```

Here is the print of stream_get_filters():

```
Array ( [0] => string.rot13 [1] => string.toupper [2] => string.tolower [3] => string.strip_tags [4] => convert.* [5] => consumed [6] => convert.iconv.* [7] => bzip2.* [8] => zlib.* )
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Comment: Please add a code example to the question so it's more clear what you do. You find a list here, check that you're using the right version: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php and see for your configuration list here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-list-algorithms.php

Comment: I've updated the post with more info. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

[PHP changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.3) for version 5.3.3 says:

> Added stream filter support to mcrypt extension (ported from mcrypt_filter)

So you need at least that version for this example to work.

Comment: One would hope that everyone is using 5.3 by now, since 5.2 and earlier are no longer supported. Assuming you are on 5.3, I would hope you're on the latest revision (5.3.10 is the current, which makes 5.3.3 very old)

Comment: That's correct. But for example Ubuntu 10.04 (current LTS version, so probably used by many production servers) still [has 5.3.2 in it's repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/php5).